# Verilog loop for multiple always blocks

Tags: verilog

If I have more `reg` declared, every `reg` needs to have his own `always` block, for example:

```
output reg[3:0] A;
output reg[3:0] B;
output reg[3:0] C;  

always @(posedge clock) begin
    if(reset) begin
       A <= 4'b0;
    end
    .
    .
    .
end

always @(posedge clock) begin
    if(reset) begin
       B <= 4'b0;
    end
    .
    .
    .
end

always @(posedge clock) begin
    if(reset) begin
       C <= 4'b0;
    end
    .
    .
    .
end
```

What if I have a loop, lets say something like this:

```
repeat n times
    if(C<0) begin
         shift C two positions
         C <= C + 1;
    else
         shift A one position
         A <= C + 1;
end
```

As you see here, inside of `if(C<0)` block, I can't have

```
C <= C << 2;
C <= C + 1;
```

so I will need separate register to store `C` shifted, let's say it will be `output reg[8:0] shiftC`, so by the way I need separate `always` block. And of course, separate `always` block for `A` too.

My question is, how can I make this loop work, if I use multiple `always` blocks?
PS: here, number of bits is just informative, and does not matter.

Comment: It would help if you told us what you are actually trying to do, rather than what you think you need to do. ([See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/263297)).

Comment: FYI: Shift left 2 and add 1 can be written as `C <= {C,2'b01};`. For more complex procedural logic I sugest adding a combinational `always @*` block to assign `C_next` (or other name of your choice) with blocking statements (`=`), then in the synchronous `always @(posedge clock)` block assign as `C <= C_next`

Comment: @TomCarpenter I am trying to do a divider with no restoring, and I need this description that I told you about. The reason why I didn't specified this is because I needed to understand only the things that I asked .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I learned […] every `reg` needs to have his own `always` block…

I think you've got this backwards. Each register should only be assigned to by one `always` block. However, this doesn't mean you need a separate `always` block for each register! It's perfectly safe (and, in fact, quite normal) to have a single `always` block for all the synchronous logic in a module, e.g.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset) begin
        A <= 4'b0;
        B <= 4'b0;
        …etc…
    end else begin
        …etc…
    end
end
```

> What if I have a loop, lets say something like this:

You can't do that in a loop.

Verilog loops are for generating multiple copies of repeated logic. They are not a substitute for clocked logic -- if you need to perform multiple actions, you will probably need to make them happen on separate clocks, and implement them in a state machine.

Depending on what you need to happen, there *might* be some way to "unroll" the loop and make several iterations happen in a single clock. However, you will need to be very careful about how you implement this. Making multiple levels of branching logic run in a single clock cycle is generally inadvisable; data dependencies will severely limit the clock rate of such a design.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood part about loops, but at part about `every reg needs to have his own always block` I don't know who to trust. When I wrote many registers in same `always` block, my teachers told me to never ever do that again, because is software like. In every single example given by them, there were all the time separate `always` blocks for every register.

Comment: @ClaudiuM Your teacher, and those examples, are wrong. Breaking up `always` blocks that way will inevitably end up forcing you to replicate logic (like the `if (reset)` in my example); having multiple copies of that logic makes it easy to accidentally change one but not the other, leading to unexpected behavior.

Comment: Writing FSMs would be a nightmare if each `reg` needed its own always block. It is definitely **not** a Verilog requirement, nor a requirement from any other HDL I'm aware off. Perhaps the _"every reg needs to have its own always block"_ is an assignment requirement; a challenge to make you think.

Comment: @Greg I also asked other people who are advanced in Verilog and actually graduated school. They all told me that I need an `always` block for every register. I would like to trust you, rather than trust them. Their examples of circuits and add/sub/mult/div algorithms are also wrong described, and I'm not the only one here who have this problem.